# How to be more memory efficient with tab bars and nav controllers?

Tags: ios, memory-management, tabbar

***Background:*** I have a tab bar controller which currently contains 4 tabs. 3 of the tabs are navigation controllers which display a hierarchy of table views for viewing, editing, and creating data. The data is generally NSStrings that are taken from the user and stored in a global variable (data needs to be accessed from multiple views in the hierarchy, as well as multiple tabs).

***Problem*** I have noticed that my app uses quite a bit of memory as soon as it starts **(~11mb**). However, as I scroll through the table views and use the nav controller to access more table views and edit some data, the memory usage quickly goes up to nearly 20mb. The worst part is that popping out of the detail view controllers does not cause the memory usage to decrease. It will hover around **20-21mb**, and if I repeat the process I seem to get higher and higher memory usage. I have tested my app in Leaks and I have solved all issues there. I suspect that my inactive view controllers are still sitting in memory, even as they are not currently displayed. Is there any way to release unneeded view controllers in  a navigation controller's hierarchy, or even the inactive view controllers from the tab bar? I have been reading Apple's docs and they strongly suggest implementing `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` and `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` in view controllers and the app delegate alike. I really don't know where to start with those methods. What controllers can I release and how do they get recreated? I assume that I'm responsible for that, but I would like to be sure.

Note that I have not yet gotten my app to terminate due to low memory usage, but enough repititions of data entry (lot of view controller pushing and popping) will cause it to slow to a crawl.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a few navigation controllers (root controllers for your tab controller) would cause such a high memory footprint. My own application has 7 root controllers that are all initialized (although the view for each isn't) on startup and my app's initial footprint is about 1.5MB.

Also, UINavigationController *does* release controllers when you pop them off the stack so unless you're retaining them somewhere then they should be being freed.

Are you *sure* you don't have any major leaks elsewhere? Have you used Instruments to see what classes are using the most memory?

Comment: Luke is that initial footprint taken from Object Allocations or from Activity Monitor?

Comment: I apologize, I had neglected to re-test the cycling of view controllers after I fixed the leaks. I have done so, and I now find that popping the controllers does, indeed, drop the memory usage. My max usage is just above 30mb, with ~22mb when popped back (Activity Monitor). The most interesting thing I have found is in Object Alloc, I find a very high allocation ratio and overal allocations (~50% of total allocations) on GeneralBlock-16. I see that a good 70% of those are the responsibility of CoreGraphics, CGFontGetGlyphForGlyphName, for which there is little to no information about!

Comment: It's not hard to guess what CGFontGetGlyphForGlyphName does, however. Clearly it's part of text layout. If you're getting it a lot more than you think you should, perhaps you are constantly recreating UILabels that you should be caching, or perhaps you have a large UITextView.

Answer (score 3):

If repeatedly viewing the same screens leads to higher and higher memory usage, you have a leak. The fact that Leaks doesn't detect it doesn't mean you have no leaks. Even a garbage collected program can leak if you hold onto data you shouldn't be holding onto.

Pull up Instruments with Object Allocations template and see what's eating the majority of your memory. Look at what's still in memory that shouldn't be. If you think your view controllers should be getting out of memory, put an `NSLog()` in their `-dealloc` and confirm that they really *are* getting out of memory.

You should implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your view controllers, and Apple gives guidence on how to implement it in [Memory Management of Nib Objects](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html). At the very least you should implement a logging statement in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` so you know if you're receiving warnings. But that's unlikely the actual problem. Failure to implement this method doesn't cause memory leaks, it just prevents you from releasing memory as fast as you could in low-memory situations.

Are you following the #1 rule of Cocoa Memory management: Thou shalt use accessors? Do not mess with your instance variables directly, and most memory management issues go away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in iPhone OS 3.0+ `UIViewController` subclasses should usually just implement [viewDidUnload](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) instead of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. It automatically gets called in low memory systems if the current `UIViewController` view is not being displayed. You should release things like `IBOutlets` there, which will cause the actual views to release, which is fine since if they end up being displayed again `viewDidLoad` will be called first.

`didReceiveMemoryWarning` is still appropriate in some cases if you have some sort of memory you can shed even when the `UIViewController` is being displayed (like caches).